# Passwort reset link in new-account e-mail

Tags: magento-1, customer, email, password

I'm trying to get the **reset password link** into the **new account mail**, right after **registration**. My attempt right now is:

> theme/template/customer/resetlink.phtml

```php
if ($user->getId()) {
    $newResetPasswordLinkToken = Mage::helper('admin')->generateResetPasswordLinkToken();
    $user->changeResetPasswordLinkToken($newResetPasswordLinkToken);
    $user->save();

    echo "https://thisismyshop.com/customer/account/forgotpassword/?id=" . $user->getId() . "&token=" . $newResetPasswordLinkToken;
```

> Layout handler in customer.xml

```php
<resetlink_handle_new_account_mail>
  <block type="core/template" name="resetlink" template="customer/resetlink.phtml" />
</resetlink_handle_new_account_mail>
```

> E-Mail Template:

```php
 {{layout handle="resetlink_handle_new_account_mail" user=$customer}}
```

I can call the template via block, which works:

```php
{{block type='core/template' area='frontend' template='customer/resetlink.phtml'}}
```

But I have to transmit **$customer** as user to the template file in order to create a new token and generate the correct reset-url.

What am I doing wrong?

> Getting Error: *Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getId() on
>   null*

Thank you for your help!

Is there a more straightforward possibility? Right now the token is empty, if I use the same {{}} as used in the reset password template.

Answer (score 0):

I already found a solution by writing an observer on `customer_register_success` which creates the password token.
If then the new account mail is sent, I use the same Link as used within the password reset mail, which then includes the token, as it has been set previously.